# Null db values and defaults

Tags: t-sql

I have 2 fields that I'm adding to a current database table with data in it. One is a bit and one is an int. If I am setting defaults for both, should I just set them to not null since there is no case where they would be null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will ever need to store data where you need the ability to indicate "we don't know" then you may consider allowing null values.

For example, I store data from remote sensors. When I am unable to retrieve the sensor data, like due to network problems, I use null.

If, however, you require that a value always be present, then you should use the `NOT NULL` constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that would do the trick. If you set those columns as not null and you don't specify a default value, you'll definitely get an error from the DB.